# Definition of $C^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I know that this is (at least ) the set of all continuous functions $f(x)$ which are first order differentiable.

But do the first order derivatives $f'(x)$ have to be continuous as well if $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes that's the definition.

Comment: We call $C^1$ the space of continuously differentiable functions.  "Continuously differentiable"  means (as noted) a function whose derivative is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is exactly the set of all differenitable functions in a space whose first order derivative is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $I$ is an interval, we usually define $C^0(I)$ as the set of continuous functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and for $n>0$ we define $C^n(I)$ as the set of differentiable functions whose derivatives are in $C^{n-1}(I)$.

$C^n(I)$ is a vector space $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, and when $I$ is closed and bounded, we can equip it with the norm
$$||f||:=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sup |f^{(i)}|$$
Where $f^{(n)}$ is the n-th derivative of $f$ (and $f^{(0)}=f$).